# does training make the abdominal muscles wider and not just thicker?

Tags: abdominals

I noticed my abdominal muscle didn't get "taller" or thicker but they got wider...like really wider.

I just watched some progress pictures and my abdomen is really wider.

Is the fact that my abdomen got wider related to my training or  is it something that happens to anyone with age?

I ask cause a lot of young people have protruding but really tiny abdomens while mine look like wide fans and I used to have the tiny version too.

My abdomen training is mostly weighted hollow planks and just reached 30 seconds with 165 pounds on my butt (a friend standing on me) and sometimes I do leg lifts with toes to bar.

Comment: Please add some basic info like gender, age, weight.

Comment: I'm having trouble deciphering what exactly you're trying to explain. A visual might help? If you're concerned about the shape of your abdominals, that's largely due to genetics and nothing you can do about it. If you're asking about the width of your abdominal section you may have put on some visceral fat?